# How to add custom fields (such as District, Ward or Street) in Table Rate Shipping Method in Magento 2?

Tags: shipping-methods, magento-2.1.1

As the question title, I wanna add some custom fields (dropdown) as District, Ward or even Street in Table Rates Shipping Method on Magento 2. How can i do it?

Thanks.

Comment: check this [tutorial](http://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/)

Answer (score 0):

Only the province, ward and commune can not do

Magento2 provides country and regions and cities as dropdown option in addresses. This module provides flexibility of managing this regions for each country

https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-regions-manager